# How to split the output of this array to 2 variables instead of 1

Tags: arrays, matlab, neural-network

I am working with neural network for my little robot in MATLAB.

Here is the code I have, 
This returns the lefts and rights' value on realtimeleft.

```
[realtimeleft realtimeright]=sim(myffnn,[lefts,rights]')
```

I would like it to return the lefts value on realtimelefts, and rights value on realtimeright.

What am I doing wrong?

The current output is:

```
realtimeleft =

-107.4691
96.8685


realtimeright =

[]
```

How can I get 96.86 to be displayed in realtimeright?

Comment: Why not just use `realitime(1)` and `realtime(2)`?

Comment: I don't have too much experience on matlab so I don't know the way you are suggesting. 
Is there a mistake I'm making in my code?

Comment: @beaker oh I understood what you mean , thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not working as you expect because `sim` (sing the legacy interface) is a function with three or more output arguments, of which the [first two are time and state](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/using-the-sim-command.html).

Now calling `[realtimeleft realtimeright]=sim(myffnn,[lefts,rights]')` you get the first two output arguments, time is assigned to realtimeleft and state is assigned to realtimeright.

There might be some crazy 1-line version, but I strongly recommend to use three lines of code, everything else will be confusing:

```
[realtime state]=sim(myffnn,[lefts,rights]');
realtimeleft=realtime(1);
realtimeright=realtime(2);
```

Instead of the last two assignments, you could also use `realtime(1)` and `realtime(2)` directly in your code.

Comment: I would recommend not even assigning `realtimeleft` and `realtimeright`. If you really want something more descriptive than the indices you could always assign `LEFT=1; RIGHT=2;` and then use `realtime(LEFT)`.

Comment: Thank you so much to both of you :) @beaker